# Enable Powershell logging - missing GPO

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, group-policy, logging, powershell-v5.0

I want to enable script block logging for powershell. I have installed this new feature with a windows server 2016 VM. Now i want do test this with Windows server 2012 and Windows server 2008. First I installed PowerShell 5.0.

Now I want to aktivate logging with a Group Policy. But i can't find the Policy in: Group Policy Editor: Administrative Templates → Windows Components → Windows PowerShell → Turn On PowerShell Script Block Logging

How to add this policy? or How to enable script block logging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script Block Logging can be enabled via registry:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScriptBlockLogging`

`EnableScriptBlockLogging = 1`

Not sure how to do this via GPO though.

Answer (score 1):

According [settings reference](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=25250) this parameter defined in `powershellexecutionpolicy.admx` group policy template.

You can:

- Download and install [group policy templates for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48257) on your workstation

or

- Simple copy policy teplates from Windows 2016 VM
  `c:\windows\PolicyDefinitions` to domain policy definitions storage
  on `SYSVOL\Policies\PolicyDefinitions` folder (all domain computers search policy definition in this place)

or

- Simple copy policy teplates from Windows 2016 VM
  `c:\windows\PolicyDefinitions` to same folder on your workstation